# "Sorry, an internal error has occurred and your request was not completed." when attempting to share a project

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to share a google apps script project created using clasp. when I go to scripts editor i want to share it with other team members that are receiving an error of "Library with identifier XYZ is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don´t have read access?)"

Comment: Can you share your clasp.json file.

Comment: {
    "scriptId":"xyz",
    "fileExtension": "ts"
}
changed script id content for privacy sake

Comment: Hello @Beyonder, are you using the above mentioned library? Moreover, can you confirm you have included it correctly and you have access to it? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
It seems that this only happens if going through File->Share.
If I go through My Projects -> select project -> Share Sheet + Script, then it works :shrug.